# bind emacs evil window commands to g prefix

Tags: vim, emacs, evil-mode

I'm new to Emacs. I have Emacs 24.3.1 with evil mode installed. I'm trying to bind `gw` as a prefix to the various `evil-window` functions. For example, I would like `gwl` to focus the window to the right, and `gwh` the window to the left. Of course, this is done in vim like so: `nnoremap gw <c-w>`.

In `.emacs.d/config/init-bindings.el`, I added:

```
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g w h") 'evil-window-left)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g w j") 'evil-window-down)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g w k") 'evil-window-up)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g w l") 'evil-window-right)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g w v") 'evil-window-vnew)
```

And emacs reports this error:

```
error: Key sequence g w h starts with non-prefix key g w
```

- How do I make `gw` a prefix key?
- Is there any reason this might be a bad idea (conflicts with important emacs defaults)?

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question (and not your answer), I managed to map `gwh` to evil-window-left doing the following:

- is `gw` bound to an action ? Asking the help with `C-h-k gw` told me yes.
- `gz` isn't, so using `gzh` worked out of the box:

  ```
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "gzh") 'evil-window-left)
  ```
- so un-mapping `gw` allowed to use `gwh`:

  ```
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map "gw" nil)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "gwh") 'evil-window-left)
  ```

ps: you still can fill paragraphs with M-q

pps: I myself like windmove with Super key more :)

```
    (require 'windmove)
    (windmove-default-keybindings 'super)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the key piece of information I was missing is that `(define-key evil-normal-state-map "gw" nil)` is the way to `unmap` in evil... I guess. Also, `C-h-k gw` waits indefinitely for a terminating key (pressing enter makes it read the input as `gw<enter>`). Any idea how to get it to accept `gw` ?